# Errors on kitchen converge step

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen, musicbrainz

I'm trying to setup listenbrainz server https://github.com/metabrainz/listenbrainz-server/ but i have little/no knoledge about chef/ Vagrant setup.
I noticed 2 error in log file

https://gist.github.com/samithaj/dfb99dac67ca9b52ce9d

1. ERROR: Failed to list data bag items in data bag: "ssh_known_hosts"
2. Kitchen::ActionFailed
   Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sh -c '

I tried googling but the results were specific on problems so i could't find i solution relevant to my setup

Answer (score 0):

Your error is [here](https://gist.github.com/samithaj/dfb99dac67ca9b52ce9d#file-log-L280) in the log output:

```
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.560559 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: ---- Begin output of ["useradd", "-g", "sysadmin", "-d", "/home/opscenter", "opscenter"] ----
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.564470 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: STDOUT: 
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.566426 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: STDERR: useradd: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.602598 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: useradd: cannot lock /etc/subuid; try again later.
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.607486 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: ---- End output of ["useradd", "-g", "sysadmin", "-d", "/home/opscenter", "opscenter"] ----
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:36.612374 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: Ran ["useradd", "-g", "sysadmin", "-d", "/home/opscenter", "opscenter"] returned 16
I, [2016-03-06T11:43:37.032755 #6908]  INFO -- development-ubuntu-1404: [2016-03-06T06:13:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
E, [2016-03-06T11:43:37.339132 #6908] ERROR -- development-ubuntu-1404: Converge failed on instance <development-ubuntu-1404>.
```

There's a problem with an OS lockfile. I suspect this is a transitory error, I would suggest deleting your virtual machine and build a fresh one:

```
kitchen destroy
kitchen converge
```